# Running unit tests on TFS 2010 from msbuild proj file using VS 2012 projects

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, mstest

Up until a few months ago, we were compiling a 2010 sln using TFS 2010 and executed our unit tests using a vsdmi and all was well. We then upgraded to VS 2012 and configured our TFS 2010 server to compile our code using a MSBUILD proj file and TFS 2010 is no longer executing the unit tests. Does anyone know what I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

On Visual Studio TFS 2010, unit tests are executed with MS Test , but on 2012 they are executed with Test Runner, it's another Layer, 
You can personnalize your processus of build with old layer MS Test for give same results

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms253138.aspx

Access to your `Process section of Build`, check `Automated Test` and custommize your layer in `Add Edit Test Run`